# Why do I get 'No data found' when passing a string variable into PL/SQL where clause

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to get a user's ID number based on their network ID, but for some reason when I try to pass in their network ID in the `WHERE` clause of the `SELECT` statement in this PL/SQL I get an error.

However if I output what is in `user_rec.USER_NAME` to the console there is a valid value, and if I hardcode a string ex: `WHERE UserID = 'USERNAME'` it also works as expected.  It seems to only fail for string variables in the `WHERE` clause.....?

```
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512 at line 12
01403.00000 - "no data found"
*Cause
*Action
Error at line 1
```

**PL/SQL:**

```
DECLARE
   v_addressbooknum number;
   v_addresstype nchar(3);
CURSOR SELECT_PORTALUSERS is
SELECT USER_NAME FROM PERSONS WHERE DEFAULT_GROUP <> 'Employees';
BEGIN
  FOR user_rec IN SELECT_PORTALUSERS LOOP
    -- Fetch Address Book # based on user ID
    SELECT ABNum INTO v_addressbooknum
    FROM OWNER.TABLE@DBLINK
    WHERE UserID = user_rec.USER_NAME;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

=====================================================================
**EDIT**

Here is the new PL/SQL I ran based on DCookie's suggestion

```
DECLARE
   v_addressbooknum number;
   v_addresstype nchar(3);
CURSOR SELECT_PORTALUSERS is
SELECT USER_NAME FROM PERSONS WHERE DEFAULT_GROUP <> 'Employees';
BEGIN
  FOR user_rec IN SELECT_PORTALUSERS LOOP

    -- DEBUG --
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DEBUG Found User: ' || user_rec.USER_NAME);
    -- END DEBUG --
    BEGIN
        -- Fetch Address Book # based on user ID
        SELECT ABNum INTO v_addressbooknum
        FROM OWNER.TABLE@DBLINK
        WHERE UserID = user_rec.USER_NAME;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('User: '||user_rec.USER_NAME);
    END;
  END LOOP;
  -- DEBUG --
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DONE');
  -- END DEBUG --
END;
```

And here is the output I get, you can see if finds values in the `user_rec.user_name`.  And if I hardcode one of the user IDs found into the where clause it works properly (meaning the User IDs exist in the tabled the fetch is being executed against).

```
DEBUG Found User: USER846
User: USER846
DEBUG Found User: USER241
User: USER241
DEBUG Found User: USER780
User: USER780
DEBUG Found User: USER783
User: USER783
DEBUG Found User: USER294
User: USER294
DONE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your FOR loop ever selects a user_name that is not in the remote table (ex: remote column has trailing blanks) you'll get this error, because you're not handling any exceptions on the select statement. I'd debug this by adding an exception handler and writing debug info:

```
BEGIN
  FOR user_rec IN SELECT_PORTALUSERS LOOP
    -- Fetch Address Book # based on user ID
    BEGIN
    SELECT ABNum INTO v_addressbooknum
    FROM OWNER.TABLE@DBLINK
    WHERE UserID = user_rec.USER_NAME; -- TRIM column or variable if necessary
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('User: '||user_rec.user_name);
    END;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: So I added a `DBMS_OUTPUT` at the beginning of the loop (before the BEGIN), and added the `EXCEPTION` as you recommended.  But now I get: "DEBUG USERNAME: USER1 \n User: USER1 \n DEBUG USERNAME: USER2 \n User: User2"  So it finds a value, but still thinks there isn't one there.

Comment: The fact that your exception handler is firing indicates the value is not there. Are you certain there isn't any sort of extra whitespace in the the username? Try: SELECT DUMP(USER_NAME,17) FROM PERSONS WHERE DEFAULT_GROUP <> 'Employees'; at a command prompt and make sure the values returned look reasonable.

Comment: I'll post what Im running and the DBMS output in an edit above so I can use more characters and format it properly.  The `FOR` loop is definitely looping for each user ID.

Comment: Another way to check for white space it to concatenate a marker on each end. For example: `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('User: #' || user_rec.username || '#');` OTOH, `DUMP` is more exact.

Answer (score 2):

It just seems that not all users that are in PERSONS are also in v_addressbooknum.

Try the following sql to find all users that exist in PERSONS but not in v_addressbooknum

```
SELECT USER_NAME FROM PERSONS
MINUS
SELECT userID FROM v_addressbooknum
;
```

Then use

```
Exception
  When NO_DATA_FOUND Then
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('no data found');
End;
```

to handle this error condition.

Do not use "when others" to handle "no data found".

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was a dataformatting issue, I `TRIM`ed both the column and the variable in the `WHERE` clause and it seems like it properly returns data...  Odd since they are both `VARCHAR`s

```
DECLARE
   v_addressbooknum number;
   v_addresstype nchar(3);
CURSOR SELECT_PORTALUSERS is
SELECT USER_NAME FROM PERSONS WHERE DEFAULT_GROUP <> 'Employees';
BEGIN
  FOR user_rec IN SELECT_PORTALUSERS LOOP

    BEGIN
        -- Fetch Address Book # based on user ID
        SELECT ABNum INTO v_addressbooknum
        FROM OWNER.TABLE@DBLINK
        WHERE TRRIM(UserID) = TRIM(user_rec.USER_NAME);
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('User: '||user_rec.USER_NAME);
    END;
  END LOOP;

END;
```

Comment: If applying TRIM to your data solves your problem, then this is exactly what I was trying to tell you was wrong. In one of your schemas, the user_name field has whitespace in it. It is really not a data formatting issue, it is a data issue.

Comment: @DCookie - Yes I misunderstood what you were saying, I read it as the value was blank/null, not that it was a data mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

could you please put the table definition and a couple of rows?

i think that

```
SELECT ABNum INTO v_addressbooknum
        FROM OWNER.TABLE@DBLINK
        WHERE UserID = user_rec.USER_NAME;
```

the column UserId from table@dblink is not the same column as user_rec.USER_NAME;

in the code that you have posted, the select goes with the exception with no_data_found on each row

Comment: I cannot, I sanitized the actual table, link, & column info for security reasons.  It did turn out to be a data match, where one table has trailing blanks and the other did not.